# Plugin closure and parsing params

Tags: image, plugins, parameters, firebreath

I am writing a firebreath plugin that is supposed to display some object.

There are many cases of failure, since it is communicating with local software.

In case of a failure I want to close the plugin and to display a regular image instead. Or to get an image URL as a parameter, to parse the file and display it.

Both options are acceptable.

So-

- What is the better option?
- How do I totally close the plugin?
- How do I parse parameters that are passed form the object tag?

I tried plugin->getParam("Name"), but didn't get the valueI passed.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
 <div id="plugincontainer">
    <object id="myplugin" type="application/x-myplugin" width="100" height="100">
    </object>
 </div>
```

You should be able to remove the plugin like this:

```
 document.GetElementById('plugincontainer').innerHTML = "";
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
 $("#plugincontainer").empty();
```

This will result in a call to onWindowDetached inside of Firebreath where you can unload your code.

You're then able to add new HTML into the DOM:

```
 $("#plugincontainer").append("<img src='images/my.jpg' />");
```